# Relacao entre entidades do banco de dados (1-n e 1-1 entre duas entidades )no dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou tentando criar uma relacao entre duas entidades 1-1 e 1-n.
Usuario pode ter N tasks e uma task so pode ter 1 usuario.

Meu codigo esta da seguinte maneira:

```
public class TaskMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TaskModel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TaskModel> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(250);
        builder.Property(x => x.Status).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.UserId);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.TasksList).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    }
}


    public class UserMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserModel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserModel> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(X => X.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);

        builder.HasMany(user => user.TasksList).WithOne(task => task.User).HasForeignKey(task => task.UserId);
    }
}

public class TaskModel
```

{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? Name { get; set; }
public string? Description { get; set; }

```
public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }

public int? UserId { get; set; }
public virtual UserModel? User { get; set; }
```

}

public class UserModel
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? Name { get; set; }
public string? Email { get; set; }

```
  public List<TaskModel>? TasksList {get; set;}
```

}

```
private readonly TaskSystemDBContext _dbContext;
```

public TaskRepository(TaskSystemDBContext taskSystemDbContext )
{
_dbContext = taskSystemDbContext;
}

public async Task<List> GetAllTasks()
{
return await _dbContext.Tasks
.Include(x => x.User)
.ToListAsync();
}

```
private readonly TaskSystemDBContext _dbContext;
```

public UserRepository(TaskSystemDBContext taskSystemDbContext)
{
_dbContext = taskSystemDbContext;
}

public async Task<List> GetAllUsers()
{
return await _dbContext.Users.Include(x => x.TasksList).ToListAsync();
}

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

{
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

```
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles; });

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<TaskSystemDBContext>(
        options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBase"))    
    );


builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRespository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();
```

Estou obtendo os seguinte retorno na busca por usuarios:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "tasksList": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "futemax",
        "description": "futemax",
        "status": 1,
        "userId": 3,
        "user": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Aqui ele esta me retornando o userID e user null, mas estou obtendo esse dado dentro do usuario já, é uma consulta redundante.

Ja na busca por Task estou obtendo o seguinte retorno:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "futemax",
    "description": "futemax",
    "status": 1,
    "userId": 3,
    "user": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "tasksList": [
        null
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Tenho acesso ao ID usuario porem sem preencher o campo nome e email, tambem esta me retornando uma tasklist que nao deveria ser retornado aqui ja que estou olhando tasks e nao quero obter o retorno de todas as task do usuario que esta associado aquela task.